# Downloading CSV via AJAX

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, lowpro

Can you use AJAX to download a generated csv file from a web application? If so does anyone have any kind of reference that I could be pointed towards?

EDIT: Sorry I should have mentioned I am using Prototype's Ajax.Request and I looked in firebug's response tool and the generated CSV is the response, I just need to get it to pop up with the save file option after has been generated by the Ajax.Request

Answer (score 4):

This is a known limitation of Ajax requests, you will need to use JS like:

```
window.location='download-csv.rb';
```

Instead of using an Ajax request. Another way is to change the location of a hidden Iframe, but this has it's own pro's/con's.

You will never get an Ajax request to display the 'file save' dialog, no matter what HTTP headers you send.

Answer (score 1):

In light of your latest edit, to make your CSV file trigger a file download (instead of rendering in the browser), there's no need for Ajax.

Instead, the solution is to have your back-end system add this HTTP header when the CSV file is requested:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=<your_filename.csv>;
```

Your implementation here depends on the back-end system you're using. If you're using Rails (as your username suggests), here's a start:

```
filename = 'your_filename.csv'
headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\""
render :layout => false
```

Comment: We are using AJAX to hide a link during the generation of the CSV, downloading a file without AJAX is not a problem and was already being done by the application, we needed to hide a link to stop users clicking the link more than once.

Comment: Try using $('#link').click(function(){$(this).hide()});

Comment: Obviously that should have been $(this).remove();

Answer (score 0):

Downloading it isn't the problem; you can download any data you like via XmlHttpRequest. The hard part is parsing it. There are several ways to parse it, from regexs to string indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "AJAX" to download *anything* .. Some people would say you shouldn't call it AJAX in that case since that term is rigorously devoted to downloading XML. But really it's just a mechanism to get data into the client w/o reloading a page. If you were loading HTML it'd be called AHAH, for CSV i guess you'd call it AHAC or AJAC? ..